# Trix editor no longer rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trix

I am trying to add actiontext/trix to my rails blog application.  I currently have 3 models, I want to use the action text for 2 of them articles and comments (the third model is devise authentication).  I have gone through the documentation installation and setup multiple times and I don't know what is wrong.  Instead of a trix editor this is what I am getting when my view for my new or edit article pages render.

[image]

Here is my form partial
_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with model: [ @article, @article.comments.build ] do |form| %>
    <p>
      <%= form.label :commenter %><br>
      <%= form.text_field :commenter, class:"form-control" %>
    </p>
    <div class="">
    <%= form.label :body %>
    <%= form.rich_text_area :body %>
  </div>
    <p>
        <%= form.label :status %><br>
        <%= form.select :status, ['public', 'private', 'archived'], selected: 'public', 
         :class => 'form-select' %>
    </p>
  
    <p>
      <%= form.submit 'Create Comment', :class => 'btn btn-outline-primary' %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
```

article.rb

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
    include Visible
    
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    has_rich_text :body
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }
  end
```

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  include Visible
  belongs_to :article
  has_rich_text :body
  validates :commenter, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }
end
```

The important part my article controller
articles_controller.rb

```
private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, :status, :user_id)
    end
```

Important part of my comment controller
comments_controller.rb

```
private
      def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body, :status)
      end
```

application.js

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.
//= require jquery_ujs 
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"
import "trix"
import "@rails/actiontext"
import "bootstrap"

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()

require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "blog",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/actiontext": "^6.1.4-1",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.4.3",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "trix": "^1.2.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3"
  }
}
```

What could be causing the trix editor to be not rendering properly?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: this is probably you didn't setup js side (or setup in the wrong way), you should make sure that you already add `trix` js package and also require it on applicaion.js, Or in case of you're using `ActionText` you could just only call command `bin/rails action_text:install`, reference: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html#installation

Comment: Yeah I used ```bin/rails action_text:install``` and I did import in ```application.js```

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem (running the latest Rails 7[Ruby 3.0.3] versions in a M1 apple machine). And, apparently, something I couldn't see was missing. So, I decided to try and create a new application just to test the `action_text` feature, I reproduced (AGAIN) all of the steps from the `rails guides` as @LamPhan mentioned, and it definitely worked out. My Trix-editor is up and running without issues. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this problem by commenting out,

```
#app/javascript/application.js

import "bootstrap"
```

I believe there were some unseen errors from that import that stops the other imports from executing properly.